# What is the name of the google-chrome package for use with yum?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, yum

I’m using the following version of Linux

```
[davea@mydevbox mydir]$ uname -a
Linux mydevbox.mydomain.com 1.3.8-18.52.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 16 17:15:34 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I’m trying to install chrome but do not seem to be able to figure out what the right package is.  I tried this

```
[davea@mydevbox mydir]$ sudo yum install google-chrome
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * amzn-main: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 * amzn-updates: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
amzn-main/latest                                                                                                                                                                     |  2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/latest                                                                                                                                                                  |  2.3 kB     00:00     
No package google-chrome available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

How do I install Chrome on my system?

Comment: `uname` is pretty useless in a case like this. More useful would be checking `cat /etc/redhat-release` or `cat /etc/debian_version` depending on whether you are using a RedHat or Debian flavor of Linux. If you are attempting to use `yum` that means the output of `cat /etc/redhat-release` would be what you need to check.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state your distro, but this should work for most of them that use YUM. The proper package names are the same for yum or apt... it is:

`google-chrome-stable` or `google-chrome-beta` or `google-chrome-unstable`

Assuming you have enabled Google Chrome's repository, [here](http://www.tecmint.com/install-google-chrome-on-redhat-centos-fedora-linux/) is an example.

Comment: @Dave No, you didn't say.. uname doesn't say your distro (Ubuntu, Red Hat, SUSE, etc) or version. But that isn't relavent I guess. Did you follow the link I posted, added the repository, and try again? If not, just download the Linux installer from https://www.google.com/intl/en-US/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html and get the RPM package and install it, it will update the repo automatically.

Comment: No, I hadn't set up the repository.  Doing so does produce some output, although it ends in errors ("Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64 (google-chrome), Requires: xdg-utils"), which I'll have to dig into.  Will also try this RPM install as well if I can't get those worked out.

Comment: @Dave it sounds like you don't have the proper dependencies, if you get them manually or get yum to do it automatically, you should be set.